# Возврат к той же позици с которой был клик после скролла

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть страница. На ней расположены блоки с контентом, по клику на название блока происходит скрол к шапке сайта. Нужно реализовать возврат к тому же блоку( с которого ушли), по клику на кнопку "Back".  Подскажите как это реализовать.  Проблема в том что блоков много, а кнопка назад одна. Якоря использовать не выходит так как нужно как-то узнавать с какого блока ушли... Буду благодарен за помощь
Набросал пример.

```js
$(function() {
  $('h2').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0},500);
    return false;
  })
})
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 780px;
}

h2 {
  cursor: pointer;
}

h2:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .3s;
  opacity: .7;
}

ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 5px;
}

ul {
  padding: 5px;
}

ul li:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #ccc;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

h1, .back {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
}

.back {
  color: darkslateblue;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.back:hover {
  transition: .3s;
  opacity: .7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <header>
        <H1>Example</H1>
        <span class="back">Back &darr;</span>
    </header>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <h2>Test2</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
                 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2>Test3</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
                 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2>Test4</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2>Test5</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2>Test6</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2>Test7</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2>Test8</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2>Test9</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2>Test10</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2>Test11</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2>Test12</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2>Test12</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2>Test12</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2>Test12</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
        </li>

    </ul>
<div>
```

Comment: Если ваша кнопка - обычный якорь(тег `a`) - всё будет достаточно просто. На каждый нажимаемый элемент вашейте `id`, а при клике на него - меняйте аттрибут `href` вашей кнопки в соответствии с `id` кликнутого элемента.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

event.pageY - расстояние от начала страницы до точки, где было произведено нажатие. Просто прокручивайте до него при нажатии на Back

```js
$(function() {
  var scroll_height = 0;

  $('h2').click(function(event) {
    scroll_height = event.pageY;
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0},500);
    return false;
  });

  $('.back').click(function(event) {
    if(scroll_height){
          $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: scroll_height},500);
    }
    return false;
  })

})
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 780px;
}

h2 {
  cursor: pointer;
}

h2:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .3s;
  opacity: .7;
}

ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 5px;
}

ul {
  padding: 5px;
}

ul li:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #ccc;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

h1, .back {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
}

.back {
  color: darkslateblue;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.back:hover {
  transition: .3s;
  opacity: .7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <header>
        <H1>Example</H1>
        <span class="back">Back &darr;</span>
    </header>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <h2>Test2</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
                 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2>Test3</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
                 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2>Test4</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2>Test5</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2>Test6</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2>Test7</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2>Test8</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2>Test9</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2>Test10</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2>Test11</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2>Test12</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2>Test12</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2>Test12</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
        </li>
        <li>
            <h2>Test12</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A adipisci aliquam at autem cum dolor dolorum ea, eos exercitationem fugiat molestiae mollitia obcaecati officiis perferendis placeat quibusdam saepe sed, sit!</p>
        </li>

    </ul>
<div>
```